# Listing files UNIX SAS

Tags: list, unix, directory, sas

i found a code that list all directories and sub directories from a path.
but it brings only the directory and the name of the file.
could you guys please help me how to bring the owner and the file size?

```
%macro list_files(dir);
  %local filrf rc did memcnt name i;
  %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf,&dir));
  %let did=%sysfunc(dopen(&filrf));      

   %if &did eq 0 %then %do; 
    %put Directory &dir cannot be open or does not exist;
    %return;
  %end;

   %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(dnum(&did));   

   %let name=%qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i));

   %if %index(%qscan(&name,-1,'/'),.) gt 0   %then %do;

        data _tmp;
          length dir $512 name $100;
          dir=symget("dir");
          name=symget("name");
        run;
        proc append base=want data=_tmp;
        run;quit;

      %end;
      %else %if %qscan(&name,2,.) = %then %do;        
        %list_files(&dir/&name)
      %end;

   %end;
   %let rc=%sysfunc(dclose(&did));
   %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf));     

%mend list_files;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DOPTNAME` is your friend here.

Read SAS documentation for **["Example 1: Using DOPTNAME to Retrieve Directory Attribute Information"](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n0jdt2eo1d9pyxn1hxjrkwhi9cdp.htm&locale=en#n03mrqupj6ggbnn19vunwt5tacwx)**

> This example opens the directory with the fileref MYDIR, retrieves all system-dependent directory information items, writes them to the SAS log, and closes the directory:
>
> ```
> %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf, physical-name));
> %let did=%sysfunc(dopen(&filrf));
> %let infocnt=%sysfunc(doptnum(&did));
> %do j=1 %to &infocnt;
>    %let opt=%sysfunc(doptname(&did, &j));
>    %put Directory information=&opt;
> %end;
> %let rc=%sysfunc(dclose(&did));
>
> %macro test; 
>  %let filrf=mydir;
>  %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf, physical-name));
>  %let did=%sysfunc(dopen(&filrf));
>  %let infocnt=%sysfunc(doptnum(&did));
>   %do j=1 %to &infocnt;
>    %let opt=%sysfunc(doptname(&did, &j));
>    %put Directory information=&opt;
>   %end;
>  %let rc=%sysfunc(dclose(&did));
> %mend test;
>
> %test
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `finfo()` function. You can do this all in a single `data` step.
[Documentation](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=hostunx&docsetTarget=p0rtd85lrdft6en1mhzqfbp55fv4.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

```
/* Macro variable to store the directory. Do not keep ending slash. */
%let directory = /my/directory;

filename mydir "&directory";

data file_list;

    length directory
           filetype $15.
           filename $1000.
           owner    $100.
           size     8.
    ;

    directory = "&directory/";

    /* Open the directory */
    did = dopen("mydir");

    /* If the directory exists, loop through all files in the directory */
    if(did) then do;
        do i = 1 to dnum(did);

            /* Get the filename */
            filename = dread(did, i);

            /* Create a filename variable and create a file ID to read its attributes */
            rc  = filename('infile', cats(directory,filename));
            fid = fopen('infile');

            owner         = finfo(fid, 'Owner Name');
            size          = finfo(fid, 'File Size (bytes)');

            /* Flag if it's a directory or file */
            if(missing(size)) then filetype = 'Directory';
                else filetype = 'File';

            /* Close the file */
            rc = fclose(fid);

            output;
        end;
    end;

    /* Close the directory */
    rc = close(did);

    keep directory filename owner size filetype;
run;
```